# Scala: how to instantiate an object using java.util.Serviceloader

Tags: java, scala, serviceloader

I have a use case that requires me to create instances of an object from JSON string representations. I am following the recommendation for the Scala factory pattern, which is to use a Singleton Object with an apply method that takes the JSON as input parameter and returns the object.
I have a further requirement to instantiate these factories using java.util.Serviceloader, which uses Class.newInstance internally to create instances. However the default constructor for objects is private. How can I get around this.

`object Factory{ def apply(input: String): MyWidget }`

Need to discover and instantiate factory objects using serviceloader

Comment: I could use a regular class and not an object for my factories. Want to make sure I am not missing anything with objects

Comment: May I ask why you need to user Java's ServiceLoader in this context? It's rather used for dependency injection-like stuff. Here you're rather defining what would be a `static` helper in Java.

Comment: Also, the point of Scala's `object` is to be a singleton. It already exists as a singleton. It doesn't make sense to instantiate a new one.

Comment: The app I am building supports end users providing their own custom plugins which are registered by the serviceloader.

Comment: Also prefer an object to a class because the plugins registered above are used in a scala DSL so want to avoid users having to type new

Comment: If you want to load and unload plugins they would most likely have lifecycle. Objects are kept in memory as long as ClassLoader isn't shutting down, and they should normally be stateless. Factory methods are stored in companions because this makes them not tied to a particular variable, you can call them with FQN (they are hardcoded then). If you are loading plugins with some `ServiceLoader` you're getting some instance from some `getService` method and that property is lost anyway.

Comment: Also: the point of sth like ServiceLoad or any other DI library is that neither the author of the class nor the user calls `new` - some DI machinery does that, so you provide just `class MyService { ... }` and something calls `new` and returns it when `MyService` is requested.